# Are there any +4 items in official material?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items

On DMG p. 285, there is a table suggesting the maximum spell level equivalent and static bonus a magic item of a given rarity should have.

*Inter alia* it suggests that a legendary item might reasonably offer a +4 static bonus to *AC, attack rolls, saving throws,or ability checks*. I know this table offers guidance for creating one's own items but I was wondering: **Are there any items in official books that have such a +4 static bonus?**

Answer (score 33, accepted):

#### *Winter’s Dark Bite*

The magic weapon [*Winter’s Dark Bite*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/665777-winters-dark-bite) was published in *Hunt for the Thessalhydra*, a short adventure published in the [*Stranger Things D&D Starter Set*](https://dnd.wizards.com/products/stranger-things-starter-set) as part of the hype train for the Netflix show *Stranger Things*. While in the Upside Down, an area of that adventure, [*Winter’s Dark Bite* acts as a +4 greatsword](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/hftt/hunt-for-the-thessalhydra#WintersDarkBiteintheUpsideDown):

> This greatsword is made of an unknown black metal. In most cases, it works as a +1 greatsword. But when used against a thessalhydra, it works as a +3 greatsword. While in the Upside Down, it works as a +4 greatsword.

While it isn’t from a core adventure publication, it is an official publication.

Answer (score 21):

### *Belt of Storm Giant Strength*

The description of the [*Belt of Storm Giant Strength*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/4830-belt-of-storm-giant-strength) states (DMG, p. 155; emphasis mine):

> *Wondrous item, legendary (requires attunement)*
>
> While wearing this belt, **your Strength score changes to 29**. The item has no effect on you if your Strength without the belt is equal to or greater than the belt's score.

This belt is the only one I know of, and it only sorta qualifies: the belt sets your Strength modifier to +9, so if you consider a +5 Strength modifier as the baseline, then the belt is equivalent to a +4 to all Strength-based rolls, including attack rolls, saving throws, ability checks, and damage rolls.

Of course, it's possible for a character's Strength modifier to be higher or lower than +5, but the vast majority of characters that need Strength reach that +5 threshold as early as possible and then never go higher, so it's reasonable to consider the belt as a +4 above that norm.

Many characters substitute the Strength modifier in their attack and damage rolls (i.e. finesse). For these characters, we can still assume that their relevant ability modifier is +5, so the improvement to their attack and damage rolls is still 4, but for these characters the benefit to Strength-based saving throws and skill checks is greater than 4.

Moreover, the belt's benefits are cumulative with the typical +X granted by magic items like weapons.

Answer (score 6):

## Possibly the Wand of Orcus, but it's randomized

With a 91-00 result on either one of its two minor beneficial properties you gain a +1 bonus to AC while attuned to it.

If you add that to the +3 bonus to AC you gain while holding the wand from its Protection property you could get a total static bonus of +4 to your AC.

Answer (score -1):

There's a couple things I can think of:

Gloves of thievery gives +5 to Dexterity (Sleight of Hand) checks and Dexterity checks made to pick locks.

There's this item, in the AL-legal module CCC-GHC-09 Swamp of Death: Giant's Bane. Weapon (longbow), rare. You gain a +2 bonus to attack and damage rolls made with this magic weapon. When fighting giants, the attack and damage roll bonus increases to +4. The bow also has the Sentinel minor property and glows faintly when giants are within 120 feet of it. For this weapon, "giant" refers to any creature with the giant type, including ogres and trolls.

Staff of the Forgotten One gives expertise in Arcana and History, which can effectively be a +12, potentially.